# URL(s) for integrating SVN with Aptana?

Tags: svn, aptana3

I have just installed Subversion 1.8.3 on my shared hosting server and would now like to integrate Aptana Studio 3 with Subversion.

I found "subclipse" but I don't see specific references to Aptana, so I'm not sure that's what I need to install.

What sites do I need to add to the Updates section in Aptana to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana Studio is based upon Eclipse, so most Eclipse plugins (including Subclipse) should work with it.